# Kivy:use multiprocessing and return Type error

Tags: python, kivy

I have meet some problem with using multiprocessing in kivy app, and get

```
TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

Here is the code:

```
class MyPopup(BoxLayout):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.orientation = 'vertical'
    self.file_chooser_multiselect = FileChooserListView()
    self.file_chooser_multiselect.multiselect=True
    self.file_chooser_multiselect.path=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
    self.add_widget(self.file_chooser_multiselect)
    self.close_button_multiselect = Button(text='close',size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    self.close_button_multiselect.bind(on_press=self.dismiss_popup)  # Use dismiss_popup method instead of dismiss
    self.upload_button_multiselect = Button(text='upload',size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    self.upload_button_multiselect.bind(on_press=self.upload_file)
    self.add_widget(self.close_button_multiselect)
    self.add_widget(self.upload_button_multiselect)


def mprocess(selection):
    
    print(selection)
    return True

def upload_file(self, instance):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(self.mprocess, self.file_chooser_multiselect.selection)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    self.dismiss_popup(instance)

def show_popup(self, instance):
    self.popupmultiselect = Popup(title='My Popup', content=self, size_hint=(None, None), size=(800, 800))  # Assign self as the content
    self.popupmultiselect.open()

def dismiss_popup(self, instance):
    self.parent.remove_widget(self)
    self.popupmultiselect.dismiss()
```

Comment: See https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6915